# Extjs 6: Adding modal window doesn't mask tbar and header

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a view which act as container for my grid.
This view owns a tbar and a header.

When I add a modal window, the header and the tbar aren't masked.

Mainview:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.customer.MyMain', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'hlx-customermain',

    controller: 'maintoolbar',

    plugins: 'viewport',
    header: {
        xtype: 'myheader'
    },
    tbar: {
        xtype: 'mytoolbar'
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'mygrid'
        }
    ]


});
```

Grid (which uses the controller to add the window)

```
    Ext.define('myApp.view.customer.MyGrid', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        xtype: 'mygrid',

        tbar: {
            xtype: 'mygridtoolbar'
        },

        controller: 'mygrid',

        store: 'MyGridStore',

        columns: [
        ...
        ]

    });
```

Function from the ViewController

```
onCustomerAddClick: function () {
        var me = this,
            addCustomerWindow = me.lookupReference('addCustomerWindow');

        if (!addCustomerWindow) {
            addCustomerWindow = new myApp.view.customer.AddCustomer();

            me.getView().ownerCt.add(addCustomerWindow);
        }

        addCustomerWindow.show();
    }
```

Even tough I add it to the ownerContainer - which is the MyMain-class - the tbar and the header aren't masked. 
See this fiddle to experience the error yourself:  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add it to it's owner or what so ever. Just do this:

```
onAddCustomerClick: function () {
    /*var me = this,
        myWindow = me.lookupReference('myWindow');

    if (!myWindow) {
        myWindow = new MyWindow();
        me.getView().ownerCt.add(myWindow);
    }

    myWindow.show();*/
    var myWindow = Ext.create('MyWindow');

    myWindow.show();
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I did this according to a tutorial I've seen. Thank you!